# Getting one to many result

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-orm

I am doing some trial and error in my django query. I'm trying to get a field with one column value beside it contains lists of elements. Basically I'm trying to figure out how to attain this result:

```
{
  feed: {},
  [{
   id: 1,
   media_id: 11
  }, {
   id: 2,
   media_id: 22
  }]
}
```

I tried in python shell this query and it gave me this result:

```
>>> query = Feed.objects.filter(Q(feedmedia__isnull=True)|Q(feedmedia__isnull=False)).values('message','feedmedia__id','feedmedia__media_id').distinct()

>>> print(query)


<FeedQuerySet [{'message': 'Classic motorcycles <3', 'feedmedia__id': 145, 'feedmedia__media_id': 152}, {'message': 'sample video', 'feedmedia__id': 147, 'feedmedia__media_id': 153}, {'message': 'Classic motorcycles <3', 'feedmedia__id': 146, 'feedmedia__media_id': 151}]>
```

On the result I understand why the 'message' (one of the field in Feed table) is included, and the problem is that I don't know how I'm going to exclude it in order to get the desired output.

These are the three models involved on this operation:

```
class Media(models.Model):
   original_url = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False, unique=False)
   small_url = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, unique=False)
   medium_url = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, unique=False)
   large_url = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, unique=False)
   uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

   class Meta:
     db_table = "media"


class Feed(models.Model):
   message = models.CharField(max_length=3000, null=True, unique=False)
   type = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, unique=False)
   category = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, unique=False)
   priority_level = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=False, unique=False)
   origin_location = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, unique=False)
   created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

   objects = FeedManager()

   class Meta:
     db_table = 'feed'


# Junction Table for Feed and Media
class FeedMedia(models.Model):
"""Model to represent gosam posts/feeds."""

   media = models.ForeignKey(Media, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)
   feed = models.ForeignKey(Feed, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)
   creator = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)

   objects = FeedMediaManager()

   class Meta:
     db_table = 'feed_media'
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't define a custom `related_name` in your `ForeignKey` fields of `FeedMedia`.

So your default reverse relation accessor would be `<model_name>_set`, e.g. `feedmedia_set`.

So if you want to access a `Media` object over `FeedMedia` from `Feed`, it would be the following:

```py
query = Feed.objects.filter(Q(feedmedia_set__isnull=True)|Q(feedmedia_set__isnull=False)).values('message','feedmedia_set__id','feedmedia_set__media_id').distinct()
```

Comment: It throws an error: "Cannot resolve keyword 'feedmedia_set' into field".

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [django rest framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/), then simply create a serializer like this:

```
class FeedMediaSerializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
       model = FeedMedia
       fields = ["id", "media_id"]


class FeedSerializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):
    media = FeedMediaSerializer(source="feedmedia", read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Feed
        fields = ["message", "media"]
```

And try like this Python shell:

```
>> query = Feed.objects.filter(Q(feedmedia__isnull=True)|Q(feedmedia__isnull=False))
>> FeedSerializer(query, many=True).data
```

Comment: Still the result is the same with mine above, the only difference is that the result is composed as OrderedDict

Comment: I don't think they will be same. Because here you should get JSON output, with message as a single string and media as list in every item of the JSON

Answer (score 0):

You can write serializers for each model, then set the specific field you want to use

```
class FeedSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   class Meta:
       model = Fedd
       fields = '__all__' # for all fields
       fields = ('field_1', 'field_1', 'field_1') # for specific fields
```

then in apiviews

```
class MyFilterView(APIView):
    def get(self, request)
         filter_data = Feed.objects.filter()#your filter
         serializer = FeedSerializer(filter_data, many=True) # many=True if are many results
         return Response(serializer.data)
```